# UBUTU 16.04 Dual boot error [busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sdb]

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Dell Inspiron 7567 with windows 10 installed. I've been trying to make a partition (via windows disk management) and installing ubuntu 16.04.
After the installation is finished and I reboot to complete the process I get the following error:

```
[ 1094.137505] VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sdb
```

I got the same error while installing UBUNTU 18